# Calculating using float and int order of operation

Tags: c

I’m new to programming, and I’m taking a class and I’m having difficulty answering my homework question. I’m not asking anyone to do my homework for me, I just don’t understand how the order of operations would work in the c program. For instance, in the statement

```
num4 = num1 * num3;
```

do I calculate the value of `num4` based off of the previous statements value of

```
num1 = num1 + num2 * num2;
```

or do I calculate with the declared value of

```
int num1 = -2;
```

[image: this is the homework question]

Comment: presumably the first one.

Comment: I would expect you're to fill in the table as if those lines of code were executed in sequence in an actual program, so each step modifies the last set of values.

Comment: What would be the point of assigning to a variable if uses of the variable went back to the original value?

Answer (score 3):

An expression is evaluated using the *current* values of any inputs to that expression. So, for example:

```cpp
int a = 42;        // a is 42
a = a - 41;        // a is now 1
int b = a + 1;     // b is 2
```

will end up with `b` holding the value `2`, not `43` (which it would be if it was calculated from the original value of `a`).

---

The table in your question *could* have been ambiguous, one of two scenarios:

- Treat the statement as totally independent of previous ones; or
- Process them sequentially with effects carried forward.

I'm pretty certain it's the second case because, if it's the first, the third statement makes no sense because there's no *values* for `num1` or `num2`.

---

Hence (the smallest "doing of your homework" that illustrates the concept adequately):

```cpp
int num1 = -2, num2 = 4;        // num1[-2]
                                // num2[4]

float num3 = 1.25, num4 = 2.5;  // num3[1.25]
                                // num4[2.5]

num1 = num1 + num2 * num2;      // num1[-2 + (4 * 4) = 14]

num4 = num1 * num3;             // num4[14 * 1.25 = 17.5]
```

---

And, as a suggestion, watch out for the traps laid by your educator, such as:

- the order of operations (like `*` before `+`).
- what happens when you try to cram a `float` value into an `int` variable.
- The distinction between `+=` and `=+`.